# How to install hyperion 2.2 on kali linux

Tags: installation, hyperion, kali-linux

I want to install hyperion 2.2 on kali linux. This version of hyperion is different than previous: there is no .cpp files (now hyperion is C). So command
'i686-w64-mingw32-c++ Hyperion-1.2/Src/Crypter/*.cpp -o hyperion.exe'
 doesn't work.
I've also tried:
mingw32-make
bash: mingw32-make: command not found
Please, help.

Answer (score 4):

The following command worked for me to compile with no warnings or errors. Although I have not fully tested the resulting executable yet:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -ISrc/Payloads/Aes/c Src/Crypter/*.c Src/Payloads/Aes/c/*.c -o hyperion.exe
```

Running the file command on the resulting hyperion.exe gives:

```
hyperion.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Comment: What's means -I option? I putted i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --help and not found this. But works for me.

Answer (score 2):

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -I Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Payloads/Aes/c Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Crypter/*.c Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Payloads/Aes/c/*.c -o hyperion.exe

this command works for kali 2020.3 mingw-w64 V.8 and Hyperion-2.3.1
make sure to separate -I from Hyperion-2.3.1 and make sure to include full file path i.e. Hyperion-2.3.1/Src/Payloads/Aes/c/

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Hyperion. Hyperion is a Windows application and I am not very familiar with cross compiling issues on Kali Linux. Nevertheless, I can give you two hints to point you into the right direction:

- If you want to use the makefile: `mingw32-make: command not found` means, mingw32-make is not installed. You have to use apt to install it. Something like `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64` or `apt install mingw-w64` should solve the issue. You can also use `apt search mingw` to find the corresponding package.
- If you want to build it by calling the compiler yourself: The AES dll was replaced by TinyAES. It can be found here: `Src/Payloads/Aes/c/aes.c`. So you have to add it to your source path as well.

Kind regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

hyperion 2.2 and 2.3 has a makefile, I change compiler gcc to i686-w64-ming32-gcc, and modify CFLAGS, it can compile.